# Do PlayMarket and AppStore remember inapp purchases?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

If i understood it correctly, both are storing information about inapp purchses somewhere outside the app.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9

I just want to make sure i've actually understood it correctly:
it is possible for user to reinstall app and get the features he has already paid for. And app does NOT need to have own server and remote database to be able to restore this data when user reinstalls it.

Comment: that is correct, you don't need to worry about payments, restore app. If user installs app on another phone or reinstalls app ( His/her in-app purchase flag is returned true based on his login id ).  Handling in-app purchases flow within app is ours  ( developers ) responsibility ( e.g. show additional flow , advance games level etc. Needs to be taken care by developer ).

Comment: thank you, if you will post this as answer, i'll mark it as the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is correct, you don't need to worry about payments, restore app. If user installs app on another phone or reinstalls app ( His/her in-app purchase flag is returned true based on his login id ). Handling in-app purchases flow within app is ours ( developers ) responsibility ( e.g. show additional flow , advance games level etc, virtual goodies within app. Needs to be taken care by developer ).